# Stretched Images in IE 11

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

My WordPress website runs well on Chrome and Firefox but in Internet Explorer 11 it gives stretched look for some images like in this [link](https://magazine.seine-et-marne.fr/vos-cantons/) in the first image after the map image.

I've tried to add this CSS code in my style.css of the theme but it doesn't work

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
    flex-shrink:0;
}
```

**Chrome :** 
[image: on Chrome]
**IE :**
[image: on IE]

Can you help me with that?

Comment: I try to test your site in IE 11 and image looks proper to me. This is my testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/GmT0pTpX/256.png If this is not same on your side, can you please try to post the snapshot of the issue may help us to get idea about the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT can you please check my edits

Comment: Try to refer these links and example may help to solve your issue. https://codepen.io/studiotwist/pen/XdgqmZ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226895/alternative-option-of-object-fitcontain-for-ie and https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have used the `object-fit` property which is not compatible with IE11.

[Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit)

1. You have to use that image as background image.

2 if you want fix width then height need to be auto.

3. if you want height to be fixed then width need to be auto. this way your image want stretched in any design.

I would suggest you use as background image check the snippet.

```css
.img {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff) center center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 330px);
}

p:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="here">
  <span class="img"></span>
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example</p>
    <p>Example Example</p>
    <p>Length: 111 min</p>
    <p>Example Example Example</p>
    <p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so removing it will solve the problem?

Comment: It want resolve the problem. 1. You have to use that image as background image. 2 if you want fix width then height need to be auto. 3. if you want height to be fixed then width need to be auto. this way your image want stretched in any design. I would suggest you use as background image.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer to the (off topic) question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I add one example as snippet which will help you get the desire output.