# object-fit: cover and IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, object-fit

I'm using object-fit: cover; in my CSS to line up images on a page, because they need to be the same height. It works perfectly in most browsers however IE11 is distorting the images.

I read that I might be able to use @support to fix this but I don't understand how to do this? Or is there another option that I might be able to use?

The code I have used is below - would really appreciate any help.

```
.brands {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.brands__item img {
  display: block;
  /* Make sure max-width is added */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
    
.brands__item img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 75px;
  object-fit: contain;
}   
    
.brands__item a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
    


<div class="row" style="padding: 10px 30px 40px;">
    <hr style="border-color: #000000; border-width: 2px; width: 90px; margin-bottom: 10px;" />
<h5 style="text-align: center;font-size: 2.4rem;margin-bottom:30px;">Trending now</h5>
<ul class="brands">
  <li class="brands__item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://static.prd.echannel.linde.com/wcsstore/UK_BOC_Industrial_Ntl_Store/images/steel-blue-logo-148x75.png" alt="Steel Blue logo" />
    </a>
  </li>
    <li class="brands__item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://static.prd.echannel.linde.com/wcsstore/UK_BOC_Industrial_Ntl_Store/images/dewalt-logo-103x45.png" alt="Dewalt logo" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="brands__item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://static.prd.echannel.linde.com/wcsstore/UK_BOC_Industrial_Ntl_Store/images/3m-logo-105x55.png" alt="3M logo" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="brands__item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://static.prd.echannel.linde.com/wcsstore/UK_BOC_Industrial_Ntl_Store/images/bahco-logo-125x75.png" alt="Bahco logo" />
    </a>
  </li>
    <li class="brands__item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://static.prd.echannel.linde.com/wcsstore/UK_BOC_Industrial_Ntl_Store/images/honeywell-logo-211x40.png" alt="Honeywell logo" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="brands__item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://static.prd.echannel.linde.com/wcsstore/UK_BOC_Industrial_Ntl_Store/images/metabo-logo-166x65.png" alt="Metabo logo" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- end -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code in IE 11 and the issue seems not only with `object-fit`.

1. CSS Grid part of your code doesn't work in IE 11.

   - You need to use `-ms-` prefix to elements such as `display: grid`, `grid-column` and `grid-row`.
   - `grid-template-areas` isn't supported, you can convert it to work with `grid lines`.
   - The `repeat()` notation doesn't work in IE 11. You need to write in all row and column lengths.
2. `object-fit` is [not supported by IE 11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit#browser_compatibility). You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226895/alternative-option-of-object-fitcontain-for-ie) for the fix.
3. I use `@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {}` to target IE 11 in CSS to add some codes for IE 11 to fix the issue. The added code is like below:

   ```
   @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
       .brands__item img {
           width: 130px;
           height: auto;
           max-width: 100%;
           max-height: 100%;
       }

       .brands {
           display: -ms-grid;
           -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
       }

       li:nth-of-type(1) {
           -ms-grid-column: 1;
           -ms-grid-row: 1;
       }

       li:nth-of-type(2) {
           -ms-grid-column: 2;
           -ms-grid-row: 1;
       }

       li:nth-of-type(3) {
           -ms-grid-column: 3;
           -ms-grid-row: 1;
       }

       li:nth-of-type(4) {
           -ms-grid-column: 4;
           -ms-grid-row: 1;
       }

       li:nth-of-type(5) {
           -ms-grid-column: 5;
           -ms-grid-row: 1;
       }

       li:nth-of-type(6) {
           -ms-grid-column: 6;
           -ms-grid-row: 1;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly and I wouldn't have been able to get to it without your help. Much appreciated.